# Populate Text box on access form based on the value of combo box on the same form

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MSAccess - populate text box with value from query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786993/msaccess-populate-text-box-with-value-from-query)

I have a  single form on which there exists several combo boxes and text box. one combo box value (for the Wells) will be filled independently, then I needs the text box to have its value based on the value of the wells combo box value.
I have created a query that solved the propblem partially, it requires parameter which the wells combo box value. If I ran with query a part from the form, it wroks good and asks for the parameter and it is OK.
I do think to make use of VBA, adding a code which process a SELECT statement (of the query mentioned above), then to tell it to take its parameter from the wells combo value which will ready on the form.

Can someone help on this. Can this works as I descriped.

Thanks in advance.

Mohamed

Further to my question above, I have tried the following solution:

```
   Private Sub Well_ID_Change()
Last_Ref.ControlSource = " SELECT TOP1 New_Ref FROM" & _
" BSW_Transactions WHERE BSW_Transactions.New_Ref Is Not Null AND BSW_Transactions.Well_ID = " & Me.Well_ID.Value & _
" ORDER BY BSW_Transactions.Sample_Date DESC"
End Sub
```

the Last_Ref is the text box I want to fill in with result of the embedded SELECT statement in the code. The Well_ID is the combo box which value will be the parameter of the SELECT statement. The Well_ID is number field and it displays the well_name and stores the associated ID value in the table. Upon running the  form after saving changes, the Last_Ref text box showed (#Name?). I guessed that the text box (is a number field) found a text in the combo box Well_ID, so I added ".Value" to the above syntax at the criteria Me.Well_ID. However the problem still exists.

May I mistaken in the syntax, would someone help on this. Can this works fine?

Thanks in advance.
Mohamed

Answer (score 0):

You are doing this the wrong way around. Bind the form to a table, the wizards will do it for you, then add the combobox. Choose "Find a record on my form" from the wizard. The code or macro to do this will be generated. Once this is done, selecting a record in the combo will populate the form with the data for that record.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the AfterUpdate event of your combo box:

```
Private Sub MyTextBox_AfterUpdate()
   MyTextBox.ControlSource = DLookup("WellsField", "WellsTable", "CriteriaField = '" & [MyComboBox] & "'")
   MyTextBox.Requery
End Sub
```

This will tell your TextBox to lookup the value in your Wells table and the Requery ensures the value is up to date every time your combo box is updated. Note the `'` in the criteria part of DLookup. These `'` are only required for String values.